# Mongo Repository retrieve query for object with arraylist

Tags: java, spring, mongorepository

I have the following database query,

```
db.compDoc.find(
    { "comp_id": "MY00000Y"}, 
    { doc: {$elemMatch: {file: "abc"}}});
```

which gives the result shown below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf28dd4cab0a74d4338abf9"),
    "doc" : [
        {
            "desc" : "string",
            "file" : "abc",
            "path" : "string",
            "type" : "U",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-11-21T10:58:40.065+08:00")
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to get that result using `mongoRepository`. I tried the 2 queries shown below.

**Query 1:**

```
  @Query(value = "{ 'organizationId' : ?0, 'documents.docName': ?1, 'documents': { $elemMatch: { 'documents.docName' : ?1 } }}")
        Optional<OrganizationDocument> findByOrganizationIdAndDocumentsDocName(String orgId, String docName);
```

**Query 2:**

```
@Query(value = "{ 'organizationId' : ?0, 'documents.docName' : ?1 }", fields = "{ 'documents.docName' : 'abc' }")
    Optional<OrganizationDocument> findByOrganizationIdAndDocumentsDocName(String orgId, String docName);
```

**Results:**
Get whole document for Query 1 and 2 without filtering.

Please help me to get correct result.

*Note : `organizationId` , `documents` and `docName` have matched with database field.*

Comment: Please post the 'OrganizationDocument' Object, you shouldnt need the @Query annotation.

Comment: OrganizationDocument Object is,                                                                                        

public class OrganizationDocument extends BaseMessage {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("comp_id")
    private String organizationId;
    @Field("doc")
    private List<Document> documents;
}                                                                                                                               Document Object is,

Comment: I think you misplaced params in the first query. you are using positional param 0 at both places. OrgId should be 0 and other two should be 1. @WGSSAMINTHA

Comment: may i know the query number (1 or 2), you are taking about?

Comment: Can you provide the sample query?

Comment: @Query(value = "{ 'organizationId' : ?0, 'documents.docName': ?1, 'documents': { $elemMatch: { 'documents.docName' : ?1 } }}")        Optional<OrganizationDocument> findByOrganizationIdAndDocumentsDocName(String orgId, String docName);

Comment: I tried it, still get empty result.

Comment: If i change as this, @Query("{ 'organizationId' : ?0,  'documents': { $elemMatch: { 'docName' : ?1} }}") . I got whole object without filtering by documentname.